# Adding an element in a specific location of a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have already asked a similar question, except it was for a list, but a member here recommended me to use a dictionary, so I decided to do just that.  Here is the original link.

[Adding a value to a specific location in a list of queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301194/adding-a-value-to-a-specific-location-in-a-list-of-queues)

So, I'm trying to add a new process to a specific location in the dictionary.

```
rr_dict[Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)].Add(new process {
      Proc_Id = sjf_queue.Size + 1,
      Proc_BurstTime = Int32.Parse(time_add_texbox.Text),
      Proc_Priority = Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)
});
```

When this occurs, I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: I think you can't simply tells dictionary where you want to put the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `rr_dict[Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)]` before adding it.

Dictionaries aren't ordered, so you are trying to use `rr_dict` as if it were defined as `Dictionary<int, List<process>>` and are adding a new process to the list held by key `Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, compared with this.

It may be just a case that you need something along the lines of the following before adding to the dictionary:

```
var index = Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text);
if (!rr_dict.ContainsKey(index))
{
    rr_dict[index] = new List<process>();
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is unordered. Each of its entries are returned as a key-value pair with an undefined order.

If you want a Dictionary that also keeps the order into account, use an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).

With your current code you'll try to access a key entry instead of add the given entry (which is what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is caused by the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) property of the dictionary. You're trying to access a specific location in the dictionary (i.e., the result of `Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)`). If that doesn't exist, you'll have to create it first. Something like this:

```
rr_dict[Int32.Parse(priority_add_textbox.Text)] = new Queue<process>();
```